# Laravel 5.8 - Verification & Welcome email is not sent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, smtp

when a user register on my website that runs Laravel 5.8 , Welcome email & Verification email is not sent to users but when i check the reset password mail from reset password page it works fine.

this is my ActivationMailClient.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Helpers\Themes;
use App\Models\Setting;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ActivationClientMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $crypt_email = bcrypt($this->user->email);
        return $this->view('emails.active_account')
            ->subject('Activation - Active Account')
            ->to($this->user->email, $this->user->first_name . ' ' . $this->user->last_name)
            ->from('contact@trvtour.com', 'mywebsiteName Activation')
            ->with([
                'crypt_email' => $crypt_email,
                'user' => $this->user,
                'first_name' => $this->user->first_name,
                'reset_link' => url('active_account?key=' . $crypt_email . '&u=' . $this->user->id),
                'site_name' => Setting::getByKey('site_name')->value
            ]);
    }
}
```

and this is my ResetPassword.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Helpers\Themes;
use App\Models\Setting;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ResetPassword extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $crypt_email = Themes::myCrypt($this->user->email);
        return $this->view('emails.reset_password')
            ->to($this->user->email, $this->user->first_name . ' ' . $this->user->last_name)
            ->from('contact@trvtour.com', 'mywebsiteName Reset Password')
            ->with([
                'crypt_email' => $crypt_email,
                'user' => $this->user,
                'reset_link' => url('panel/update_password/' . $crypt_email),
                'site_name' => Setting::getByKey('site_name')->value
            ]);
    }
}
```

i have cleared the cache of my laravel application and still the issue exist can you please help me with that issue ?

My .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: How do your `.env` file looks like?

Comment: i have added my .env file in my question